# Creating instance of DirectShow filter fails

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I use this function to create DirectShow filter instances which works:

```
private IBaseFilter CreateFilter(Guid category, string name)
{
    object source = null;
    Guid guid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
    foreach (DsDevice device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(category))
    {
        if ( device.Name == name )
        {
            device.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref guid, out source);
            break;
        }
    }
    return (IBaseFilter)source;
}
```

When I try to create an instance of "GPL MPEG-1/2 Decoder" filter using this function, my application crashes at **BindToObject** function. It used to works but I formatted my laptop and I'm facing this weird problem. Do you have any idea why I can't create instance of this filter?

P.S: GraphEdit can insert this filter and open property dialog.

Comment: Fails and crashes have details such as messages and `HRESULT` codes.

Comment: Actually doesn't have. When I trace the code line by line using "Step Into" and reach to BindToObject function line, suddenly when I press Step Over, application exits the function and I can't handle nothing. It's weird. For this problem I installed Windows and Visual Studio twice!

Comment: See [How to catch exceptions in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308345)